# Busca em arquivo java

Tags: java, algoritmo-de-busca

O professor passou uma atividade, que é pra você colocar os arquivos em um txt, ler, alterar e deletar... Estou programando a função busca, e não está dando certo. Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

```
public void searchUser(String login){
        String result = "";
        try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\vanes\\Documents\\WEBprog\\Archive\\login.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while (br.ready()) {
            result += br.readLine() + "\n";
            String divider[] = new String[2];//split                
            divider = result.split(";"); //split
            if(divider[1].equals(login)){
                System.out.println(divider[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro");
    }
}
```

esse é o trecho do código.
Ele deveria ler linha por linha do login.txt, através do split separar a linha em parametros de um vetor, e comparar a entrada com um desses parametros que já está definido. Me parece que ele não está passando pras outras linhas e só está lendo a primeira, quando "busco" o da primeira linha, ele devolve perfeitamente, o das outras não... por que?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cacau, tudo bom?
A sua pergunta não está muito clara, favor escreva mais detalhes.
Mas de ante mão:

1) **verifique se o caminho do arquivo encontra-se correto**

2) o seu vetor divider na posição 1, está com algum valor? se estiver **null** ele vai dar um erro no método equals. faça isso aqui

```
if(diveder[1] != null) {
    if(divider[1].equals(login)){
                    System.out.println(divider[1]);
                    break;
                }
}
```

Comment: Ao que me parece, ele não está lendo as próximas linhas. Porque assim, ele vai ler um arquivo.txt certo? Ele deveria percorrer linha por linha, mas ao que me parece, ele para na primeira e não vai adiante. Quando eu coloco no main, se for da primeira linha, ele retorna, se não for, ele não retorna nada, é como se ele não pulasse pra próxima linha. Desculpa, é o primeiro comentário que eu faço aqui haha e obrigada.